# Screenshotting a View which is longer than the Phonescreen

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I did not manage to find a Solution for the Problem through the Search.

I am currently programming an App for Public-Transport. The Results of a Search for your transportation appear on a screen and should be shareable. 
Although, when I take a screenshot of this view through code, (just the results, without the androidbar etc) it only takes what is on the screen on that moment. If the results exceed the place on the Screen, it will be cut off.

Is it possible to save the whole view? Note: The screenshot is not saved, just given to my Activity where it is passed to Gmail or whatever.

If it helps, here is the code I used for the Screenshot:

public class Screenshot {

```
public static Bitmap takeScreenshot(View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
    return bitmap;
}

public static Uri saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        return Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hopefully, someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code can help you

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b;
    if (v.getMeasuredHeight() <= 0) {
        v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    } else {
        b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        v.draw(c);
    }

    return b;
}
```